# Orientdb Java Heap Error

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

I ran a test on **Orientdb 2.2.10** using **Transnational** **graph**

With the following **Sudo code** on single thread system

```
   for(i = 1 to 1000)
{
    DB_Name = getRandomString()

    createGraphDb(DB_Name ) using OServerAdmin : if db do not exist
    gFactory = OrientGraphFactory(DB_Name ) : if db exist


    graph = OrientGraphFactory.getTx()
    previousEvent = null

    for(j=1 to 1000)
      {
        currentEvent = getrandomString()
        if(previousEvent and currentEvent != null)
              {
                   - create Vertex named currentVertex and edges between them 
                   - (from previous to current event)
              }
        else
              {
                    create vertex named current event 
              }
         previousEvent = currentEvent
      }
   graph.shutdown()

}
```

**I got the the following Exception after few iteration of my outer loop.**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.config.OStorageConfiguration.fromStream(OStorageConfiguration.java:268)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.config.OStorageConfiguration.fromStream(OStorageConfiguration.java:497)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.config.OStorageConfiguration.load(OStorageConfiguration.java:207)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.open(OStorageRemote.java:330)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:257)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPooled.internalOpen(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:445)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.openDatabase(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:308)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.acquire(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:263)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.<init>(OrientBaseGraph.java:144)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.<init>(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:78)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph.<init>(OrientGraph.java:135)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory.getTx(OrientGraphFactory.java:119)
```

Is their any problem with my sudo code or with OrientDb.

If their exist any better way, kindly please suggest.

Thanks..!

Comment: My heap size is -xmx512m.

What is suitable heap size for this kind of application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many gigs of ram do you have available? For example if you can assign maximum 8GB to the Java process, it's usually better assigning small heap and large disk cache buffer (off-heap memory). So rather than:

`java -Xmx8g ...`

You could instead try this:

`java -Xmx800m -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=7200 ...`

For further details you can read the page regarding [performance tuning on official documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Performance-Tuning.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does orientdb server also run on JVM. I mean my db is running on remote machine. So are you talking about configuring JVM of my system(in which my java program is running) or the that of remote system in which orientdb running.

Comment: Could Java heap memory problem can also occur in my remote machine on which orientdb "server.sh" is running, I am asking this because my terminal in which orient is running showing this->>>>>> "  Error executing request
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   "

Answer (score 1):

You can check heap usage with -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xloggc:$ORIENTDB_HOME/log/gc_%p_%t.log on server (can add latest XX flag only for investigation about promotion from new to old ).

You can add similar settings on your client (change gc.log option only). I've just run a java class (8u102 on Mac, with 16gb and i7), based on your pseudo code, but running 1 loop (1 db) with 1000 vertex+edges and it successfully completed the job without OutOfMemory

Bye
Claudio

Comment: Heap size provided is 512m

Answer (score 0):

In OrientDB the transactions keep changes in RAM, so if you have transactions with hundred thousands of elements it could cause this problem. I suggest you commit every X elements. I suggest to start with 1000 and then tune it based on the result.

Comment: after every inner iteration(for loop), I am committing db. graph.shutdown commits before shutting down graph instance.

Comment: Hi 
  I tested the client java (8u102) with 10 loops and I've not seen any OOM error, running for 72 minutes .

The server started Full GC only, at db number 7, with 700 vertex, (0.2sec for full, 0.5sec for app), but slowly survived for other 30 minutes, up to db 10; process size increased up 7.8gb (and 485.2% cpu)  

The client process was not huge (below 2gb) requesting low cpu %, and running a FullGC (0.6s) only once or twice for each db 

So you need more max heap on server (try 1gb), and a lot of ram (tested with 16gb ram and i7 on OSX) 

Claudio

Comment: Can add that server was using default 512m max heap and client 4gb max heap, but it used less than 1.5gb

Comment: can you please answer this>>>> Does orientdb server also run on JVM. I mean my db is running on remote machine. So are you talking about configuring JVM of my system(in which my java program is running) or the that of remote system in which orientdb running

Comment: Could Java heap memory problem can also occur in my remote machine on which orientdb "server.sh" is running, I am asking this because my terminal in which orient is running showing this->>>>>> " Error executing request java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space "

Comment: I've run a local jvm with 10 createDatabase of remote:localhost/random_name (each one with a loop of 1000 graph.addVertex ; graph.commit ; graph.addEdge; graph.commit) ; my orientdb server was running on localhost, but in another local jvm. I've added XX options on both jvm, and was checking both gc logs, together with a println of current iteration. If you connect to a different machine with you java client, on remote machine orientdb server.sh script is executed, and probably you get OOM in heap on server only. If so, then you need to trace gc in use on server process, and increase/tune heap